# Python sudoku solver using backtrack algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku, backtracking

My first attempt at a sudoku solver using the backtrack algorithm.

```
# Functions for solving Sudoku puzzles of any size

# NumPy makes it easier to work with 2D arrays
import numpy as np


def find_empty_cells(board):
    """Traverse the board and return a tuple of positions of empty cells"""
    return [(i, j) for i in range(len(board)) for j in range(len(board[i]))
            if board[i][j] == 0]


def check_rows_cols(board, cell, test_value):
    """Return True if the given number is legal
        i.e. does not appear in the current row or column
    Return False if the given number is illegal
    """
    if test_value not in board[cell[0], :] and test_value not in board[:, cell[1]]:
        return True
    return False


def check_subgrid(board, cell, test_value, subgrid_height, subgrid_width):
    """Return True if the given number is legal
        i.e. does not appear in the current subgrid
    Return False if the given number is illegal
    """
    # Find subgrid coordinates
    # Map cell coordinates to top-left corner of subgrid
    subgrid_coords = ((cell[0] // subgrid_height) * subgrid_height,
                      (cell[1] // subgrid_width) * subgrid_width)

    # Use that top-left corner to define subgrid
    subgrid = board[subgrid_coords[0]:subgrid_coords[0]+subgrid_height,
                    subgrid_coords[1]:subgrid_coords[1]+subgrid_width]

    if test_value not in subgrid:
        return True
    return False


def update_cell(board, cell, available_nums, subgrid_height, subgrid_width):
    """Try to update the current cell
    Return a two-tuple, with second element as the board
    First element is True if the cell was successfully updated
    First element is False otherwise
    """
    # Get current cell value and index
    cell_value = board[cell[0], cell[1]]
    cell_value_index = available_nums.index(cell_value)
    # available_nums is a list of numbers that could populate a cell

    # If we backtracked and the current cell has no more options, reset it and go to the previous cell
    if cell_value_index == len(available_nums) - 1:
        board[cell[0], cell[1]] = 0
        return (False, board)

    if subgrid_height == 0:  # Don't call check_subgrid if there aren't subgrids (e.g. on a 3x3 board)
        # Check all numbers from the value of the current cell (the earlier numbers have already been checked)
        for num in available_nums[cell_value_index + 1:]:
            # If the number is legal, update the cell and move on
            if check_rows_cols(board, cell, num):
                board[cell[0], cell[1]] = num
                return (True, board)
            # Otherwise, none of the numbers worked and we need to backtrack
            elif available_nums.index(num) == len(available_nums) - 1:
                board[cell[0], cell[1]] = 0
                return (False, board)
    else:  # Call check_subgrid otherwise
        for num in available_nums[cell_value_index + 1:]:
            if check_rows_cols(board, cell, num) and check_subgrid(board, cell, num, subgrid_height, subgrid_width):
                board[cell[0], cell[1]] = num
                return (True, board)
            elif available_nums.index(num) == len(available_nums) - 1:
                board[cell[0], cell[1]] = 0
                return (False, board)


def solve(board, empty_cells, available_nums, subgrid_height, subgrid_width):
    """Perform the backtrack algorithm"""
    count = 0
    while count != len(empty_cells):
        try:
            result = update_cell(board, empty_cells[count], available_nums, subgrid_height, subgrid_width)
        except IndexError:  # Subgrid dimensions might be wrong
            return [0, 0]
            # Could return None, but that gives a ValueError in main()
            # The reason is that if solve() produces an array, then main() will need to compare None with an array
            # This produces a ValueError
            # So we just never return None, instead we return a definitely incorrect array
        if result[0] is False:  # Cell was not updated, so backtrack
            count -= 1
        else:  # Cell was updated, so carry on to the next cell
            count += 1

    return result[1]


def main(BOARD, available_nums, subgrid_height=0, subgrid_width=0):
    board = np.array(BOARD)  # Make a copy of the original board
    empty_cells = find_empty_cells(board)
    board = solve(board, empty_cells, available_nums, subgrid_height, subgrid_width)
    if board == [0, 0]:
        return "Sudoku not solvable, check subgrid dimensions or numbers input onto board"
    else:
        board = [list(row) for row in board]  # Convert from NumPy array back to 2D Python list
        return board  # Solved puzzle
```

An example call to this solver might be:

```
board = [
    [0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1]
    ....
    .... 8 rows later
    ....
    [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 8, 0, 3]
]

solution = main(board, list(range(10)), 3, 3)
```

I'm mainly interested in improving the code quality and efficiency of this implementation. I've designed it to generalise to any size board, which may add some overhead, such as checking whether or not there are sub grids. I'm also aware that there are better methods, such as recursion. In fact, I have also written a recursive version, which is much faster than this, but I would still like to improve this version, as it is quite slow on some of the [diabolical](https://www.sudokuoftheday.com/about/difficulty/) rated puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple notes.

## `check_row_cols`

This function can just be:

```
def check_row_cols(board, cell, test_value):
    return test_value not in board[cell[0], :] and test_value not in board[:, cell[1]]
```

Since the expression results in a boolean value, you can return the expression itself.

## `check_subgrid`

Same concept as above:

```
def check_subgrid(...):
    ...

    return test_value not in subgrid
```